# Putting Middleware After Request Is Processed In Java

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I need to create a middleware which will be run after an HTTP request is processed and right before the response is returned to the end user in Java with using Jersey library. Currently I can do the same before the request is processed for Authorization purposes.

This is an example of my authroization middleware:

```
/**
 * Authorisation annotation for middleware.
 */
@Inherited
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Authorised {
}
```

This is where I bind it to a class:

```
/**
 * Authorisation filter class.
 */
@Provider
@Authorised //Annotation binding
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION) //Priority
public class AuthorisationFilterController implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    /**
     * Authorisation filter for reports and definition end-points.
     *
     * @param containerRequestContext request context
     */
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        // authorize user etc.
    }
}
```

So my purpose is to create another middleware like this, but this time it should be worked after the request is processed. I searched for it but could not find a proper explanation. How can I do that?

Comment: There is also a ContainerResponseFilter.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Lol, did not noticed :(. Thanks

Comment: @PaulSamsotha How can I read data from containerRequestContext, containerResponseContext without empty it?

Comment: In the request filter, you can cast the ContainerRequestContext to ContainerRequest, and you can call `cr.bufferEntity()`. This should allow you to read it again in the response filter. Or, in the same request filter, you can buffer the entity, and then read the entity and stuff it as a property of the request context.